# Is it better practice to have a column which is null part of the time, or a separate table with a foreign key?

Tags: database-design

Let's say you have a table, subject, which represents a test subject (a chemical). The testing will provide a result, pass, fail, or inconclusive. It will spend approximately 75% of it's time not-null, but while tests are being set up it would be null. A subject could never be tested more than once.

Is it better practice to have this result column in the Subject table, or have a 2nd table in which the results are inserted (with a foreign key to the associated subject) once determined?

I made these small diagrams to hopefully better illustrate what I'm asking. 'etc' is used to stand in for multiple other columns with data unrelated to the question:

[image: Diagram of the Subject table, with values ID, participant_id, subject_type, test_status, created_at, etc, and result columns]

**versus**

[image: Diagram of the Subject table, with values ID, participant_id, subject_type, test_status, created_at, and etc columns. A second table, subject_results, contains subject key (a foreign key to the Subject table), and a result column.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends more on your use cases. Your second design is *potentially* more normalized. Is it ever the case that the same `subject` is tested more than once? If so, then definitely the second case would be more suitable due to its normalization. Whereas your first case would repeat data unnecessarily which could lead to error prone data (besides duplication).

Aside from that, there's nothing wrong with making a field nullable when appropriate and there's a use case for it.

Comment: A subject could never be tested more than once

Comment: @treo Then there's nothing wrong with making your `result` field nullable. As long as there's no chance for data duplication, then the first design is fine. Usually you look to normalize tables to reduce data duplication, effectively improving data reliability.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined what "better practice" means to you, precisely, and at any rate that makes the question a poor fit for the site (answers going to be based on opinions rather than fact).

Here are some relevant facts :

If you intend to depict a relational design, then option 1. isn't even an option because the relational model does not have this thing called 'null'.

Your model in option 2. leaves out the one thing that is in fact essential, namely the fact that the cardinality on the _results side is "0-1", not just "1" as you wrote.  Leaving out the fact that the minimum cardinality is 0 hides essential information from any reader.

That said, and assuming (1) a DML like SQL which *does* have this thing called 'null', and (2) that all the needed database constraints have also been put in place, the two designs are completely information-equivalent.  Designs are information-equivalent if there exist expressions of the relational algebra that will transform every valid database value of the one schema to a database value of the other, and vice-versa back to the original (so there is a bijection between database values of the two designs).  Cutting some slack on SQL for not being truly relational because of that null thing, these expressions are (prepended A_ and B_ to distinguish tables of design 1 from tables of design 2) :

B_SUBJECT === SELECT ID, ... , ETC FROM A_SUBJECT 
B_SUBJECT_RESULT === SELECT ID, RESULT FROM A_SUBJECT WHERE RESULT IS NOT NULL

A_SUBJECT === B_SUBJECT LEFT OUTER JOIN B_SUBJECT_RESULT ON ID = SUBJECT_ID

Not every detail covered perhaps, but it does cover the gist and should suffice to make the idea clear.  The relevance is that if two designs are information-equivalent, then there are no differences between them on the *semantic* level.  So any difference must then be in the *physical* realm (or in the area of how much time is needed to write all the needed DML expressions, or in the area of how easy your DBMS makes it to do database maintenance in either design), but whether such differences should be made obvious from the kind of schema such as those you provided, is at least very debatable.